# How to pass dynamic cookie in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have added HTTP Cookie Manager and HTTP Authorization Manager in Test Plan. When run the script following response message I have received

Response code: 401

Response message: UNAUTHORIZED

{"message":"Access is Denied","severity":"danger"}

This is my cookie

_ga=###; _gid=###; _gat=#; accessInfo={###}; userInfo={###}; 574ae166fc51fa5bdbd8beef725e77d7={###}; session=.###

But when run script only partial session is pass from my above cookie data through header request.

I also tried using regular expression but not getting response.

Can anyone suggest me how and where I can pass my cookies dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If the next request doesn't have all the cookies which you can see in the previous response [Set-Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) most probably it indicates problem with the cookies.

You can check what exactly JMeter does with cookies by [enabling debug logging for the HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging), in order to do this add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change.

---

Other things to try:

1. Turn off JMeter built-in checks for cookies. In order to do this add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```
2. Play with "Implementation" drop-down value, i.e. try choosing less restrictive implementation, for example [`netscape`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265.html#ref-Netscape)

   [image: JMeter Cookie Manager Netscape]

Comment: I tried but its not work. In my web application cookies are generated using flax application . cookies are generated on the fly through request when they required.